# Centrar elemento, independiente de su ancho con porcentaje en CSS

Tags: css3

Cómo puedo posicionar un elemento que NO sea un texto, ya que para estos puedo user `text-align: center`, pero para un elemento como un div, su ancho modificará el `50%` de la posición, ya lo sé hacer con javascript, pero me gustaría hacerlo con CSS , como funcionaría esto ?, es posible ? necesitaría obtener el tamaño del div y del body DESDE CSS y hacer operaciones en este, pero.. esto es posible ?

```css
#elemento {
width: 500px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid purple;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<h6 style="text-align: center;">buaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h6>

<div id=elemento></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opcion es contener el elemento dentro de otro con las propiedades:

```
  #elementoPadrre{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
  }
```

Lo bueno de esta opción es que centra todos los hijos y también puedes centrarlos horizontalmente saludos y espero te ayude amigo

```css
#elementoPadre {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#elemento {
width: 500px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<h6 style="text-align: center;">buaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</h6>


<div id="elementoPadre">
<div id=elemento></div>
</div>
```